# Find the Assets directory in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In rails commands like javascript_path 'application' gives path to application.js

Is there a command or a way to find the root directory for javascript files?

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript root for Rails 3 and 4 is `app/assets/javascripts/`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `Dir` module

```
Dir.glob('*/**/*.js')[0].split('/')[0..2].join('/')

=> "app/assets/javascripts"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below commands

```
Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'javascripts','application.js')
```

or

```
"#{Rails.root}/assets/javascripts"
```